# View not updating when using Master-Detail form with ASP.NET MVC 4 and KnockoutJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a single page editor for data records using ASP.NET MVC 4 and KnockoutJS.  It is fairly straightforward with a table showing the records and a form to edit individual records.

When clicking 'Edit' to edit a record the form updates and the data is persisted to the database without problem.  There are two issues after this:

1. The record being edited does not update in the table after saving (i.e. the observables do not update)
2. The  controls containing the record being edited do not clear after saving.

I have no idea how to solve (1). For (2) is there some way of writing a generic extension method or function to clear ANY form after Knockout has finished with it.  I could do it with JQuery reasonably easily but I may be missing something that Knockout can do already.

The code for the page is as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<SiteDto>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Sites</h2>


<table>
    <caption>Sites</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Url</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: sites">
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: id"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: url"></span></td>
        <td><button data-bind="click: $parent.selectItem">Edit</button></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
<table>
    <caption data-bind="text: name"></caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: url" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function viewModel() {

    var sites = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()));
    var selectedItem = ko.observable();

    selectItem = function (s) {
        selectedItem(s);
    };

    save = function () {
        alert(ko.toJSON(selectedItem));
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Save",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(selectedItem),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });

    };

    return {
        sites: sites,
        selectedItem: selectedItem,
        selectItem: selectItem,
        save: save
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your points one at a time, since they are not really related.

1) The issue here is, you take your ASP.NET MVC model, and put it in an observableArray. The thing is, an observableArray will update the UI if items are added, deleted or swapped around, but it will not notify the UI of changes to a single item. So even though you're really editing the row correctly, the UI will never know. The ideal solution would be to not simple inject your MVC model into an observableArray, but to map the model to a datastructure where the editable properties of an item (id, url, name) are made observable. Untested demonstration code:

```
var rawSites = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()),
    sites = ko.observableArray(rawSites.map(function (rawSite) {
        return {
            id: ko.observable(rawSite.id),
            url: ko.observable(rawSite.url),
            name: ko.observable(rawSite.name)
        };
    }));
```

Edit: My original answer suggested a second approach that 'hacked' a UI update by removing the edited item from the observableArray and re-adding it. @Tomalak made a better suggestion in the comments: use `valueHasMutated()` on the item instead. The result is the same but it's much less hacky. Note that the above solution is in my opinion still preferable because it will perform better (less UI reflow necessary), and it is more robust when you later add more functionality to this code.

2) Depends a bit on what you want. Do you want the edit-form to stay visible or to disappear? You're already using a `with: selectedItem` binding which makes the disappear-behavior very easy: Just call `selectItem(null)` from your `save` success-callback. If you want the form to stay visible all the time, and just clear the fields, I guess the following approach would work:

```
function viewModel() {

    var sites = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()));
    var originalItem = null;
    var selectedItem = {
        id: ko.observable(),
        url: ko.observable(),
        name: ko.observable()
    };
    var selectItem = function (s) {
        // This function now copies the properties instead of using the item itself
        selectedItem.id(ko.unwrap(s.id));
        selectedItem.url(ko.unwrap(s.url));
        selectedItem.name(ko.unwrap(s.name));
        // Get a reference to s so we can update it when we are done editing
        originalItem = s;
    };
    var resetSelectedItem = function () {
        // Clear the form and reset the reference we held earlier
        selectItem({
            id: null,
            url: null,
            name: null
        });        
        originalItem = null;
    };

    save = function () {
        alert(ko.toJSON(selectedItem));
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Save",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(selectedItem),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
                // Done editing: update the item we were editing
                originalItem.id(selectedItem.id());
                originalItem.url(selectedItem.url());
                originalItem.name(selectedItem.name());
                // Clear the form
                resetSelectedItem();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("fail");
                // Clear the form
                resetSelectedItem();
            }
        });

    };

    return {
        sites: sites,
        selectedItem: selectedItem,
        selectItem: selectItem,
        save: save
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you miss a `ko.observable(` in your first code sample. Speaking of ugly hacks, you can use `valueHasMutated()` to inform subscribers of a change, but the "unnecessary reflow" issue remains. Making observable array elements is a lot more elegant. One could use separate sub-viewmodels and the mapping plug-in to make working with complex structures more pleasant.

Comment: Right! I've edited the `ko.observable(` back in. `valueHasMutated` is indeed also an option, and a better one than I suggested. I will edit my answer with your suggestion. It's still a hack, but much less of a hack than what I suggested. Personally I am not a fan of the mapping plugin so I can't really demonstrate its use here, but it is indeed a popular plugin that could be used here.

Comment: There are alternative mapping plugins like [knockout.viewmodel](http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/) if you don't fancy the "official" one. Using one has its advantages, though, especially since you can easily do partial maps that only update those parts of the view model that have actually changed, causing fewer screen updates. (Not to speak of much clearer code through a declarative approach to data mapping.)